# Which pilot hole is better for helicoil insertion, a hole with cylindrically flat surface or a hole with cylindrically tapered surface

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, mechanical

When it comes to helicoil insertion, the choice between a hole with a cylindrically flat surface and a hole with a cylindrically tapered surface depends on several factors. These factors include the specific application requirements, the desired ease of installation, the level of thread engagement desired, and the overall mechanical performance of the helicoil joint.

Hole with Cylindrically Flat Surface:
A hole with a cylindrically flat surface refers to a pilot hole that maintains a consistent diameter throughout its length.

Hole with Cylindrically Tapered Surface:
A hole with a cylindrically tapered surface gradually increases or decreases in diameter along its length, resembling a cone shape.

Comment: You choose the helicoil for hole type, so a tapered hole (like NPT) requires a tapered helicoil.  Certainly you wouldn't drill and create a tapered hole just to put a helicoil in it since that would required a tapered bolt/pipe.